# Linq nested Where() clause

Tags: c#, linq, nested, where-clause

I have Building entity and inside of that  entity i have another entity Apartment.I want to filter those buildings  which has at least one apartment with "Approved" state AND accessibility with "Saleable".

This is my Building class.

```
public class Building 
{
 public ICollection<Apartment> Apartments {get;set;}
}
```

This is my apartment class.

```
public class Apartment 
{
  public Enum State {get;set;}   
}
```

So far i have tried this code but seems like this actually does not work.

```
 var buildings = _context.Buildings.Where(apartments.Apartments
              .Any(isActive =>isActive.State == ApartmentState.Approved && isActive.Accessibility == AccessibilityState.Saleable));
```

This code is just return all list of apartments which has  at least one apartment which fulfill this condition. I do not need the rest of apartments.

Also i have tried  another way to achieve desirable result

```
var buildings = _context.BuildingsWhere(apartments => apartments.Apartments.Where(apart=> aapart.State == ApartmentState.Approved && apart.Accessibility == AccessibilityState.Saleable));
```

In this particular case i have got this error

**operator cannot be applied to operands of type bool and IEnumerable**

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the Any clause:

```
var buildings = _context
    .Buildings // For all my buildings
    .Where(b => b.Apartments // I want the ones where
        .Any(a => a.State == ApartmentState.Approved // There is at least 1 approved
            && a.Accessibility == AccessibilityState.Saleable)); // AND one is Saleable.
```

When you're executing a `Where` the final value within the statement has to be a bool and will return an `IEnumerable` (`IQueryable`). `Any` will return `true` or `false` for you to filter on.

**UPDATE**

New requirement, only get apartments that have the filtering. After you have the buildings, if you want just the apartments that are approved and saleable, you filter again.

```
foreach(var building in buildings) {
    var saleableApartments = building.Apartments
        .Where(a => a.State == ApartmentState.Approved
                    && a.Accessibility == AccessibilityState.Saleable));
    // Do whatever.
}
```

OR if you're looking for JUST the apartments

```
var saleableApartments = _context
    .Buildings // For all my buildings
    .Select(b => b.Apartments // Select the apartments
        .Where(a => a.State == ApartmentState.Approved // where x
            && a.Accessibility == AccessibilityState.Saleable));
```

Comment: Does not this just return not only "Approved" and "Sealable" apartments but also apartments with  another states?Any() return true if  from collection at least on apartment fulfill  the predicate.

Comment: According to this, it will return all buildings that have an apartment that is approved and has a Saleable accessibility.

Comment: You want the apartments themselves? `I want to filter those buildings which has at least one apartment with "Approved" state AND accessibility with "Saleable".` So this is saying "Hey, for my set of buildings, get me the buildings that have an apartments that are approved and salable."

Comment: I want buildings but in the buildings i have IEnumerable apartment field. That file should contain only apartments which have approved and salable status.

Comment: So you're asking for something different. What's your end goal?

Answer (score 1):

From the comments under @BlueEyedBehemoth answer I would suggest:

```
var filteredBuildings = _context
    .Buildings
    .Select(b => new { apparments = b.Appartments
        .Where(a => a.State == ApartmentState.Approved
                          && a.Accessibility == AccessibilityState.Saleable) } )
    .Where(b => b.apparments.Any());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario needs a join in your linq query. You can write something like:

```
var apartments = from building in _context.Buildings
                join apartment in _context.Apartments on building.Id equals apartment.BuildingID
                where apartment.State == ApartmentState.Approved 
                && apartment.Accessibility == AccessibilityState.Saleable
                select apartment ;
```

or you can also write  a sub query :

```
var buildings = _context.Buildings
                  .Select(building => new 
                          { 
                             Building = building ,
                             Apartments = _context.Apartments
                                       .Where(apartment=>
                                        building.Id == apartment.BuildingId &&
                                        apartment.State == ApartmentState.Approved &&
                                        apartment.Accessibility == AccessibilityState.Saleable)
                           });
```

Comment: Got error 

the type of one of the expressions in join clause is incorrect

Comment: You're getting all apartments, what if they're not in the building?

Comment: @NeoXX please update your question with Building and Apartment Entity code

Comment: @BlueEyedBehemoth it's an inner join, will bring the apartments related to that building

Comment: @EhsanSajjad You added that to your sub-query after my comment lol